# VS code : How to set up same Material theme as in Sublime?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't find the same Material Theme Kit i use in SublimeText for VS Code

This is what I want:

[image]

This is what I get installing Material Theme Kit for VS Code :

[image]

It's not a big difference for JS files but Typescript files are almost not syntax colored

Answer (score 0):

This one is a derivate of the Sublime version: [Material Theme Kit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.Theme-MaterialKit)

To install, either follow the instructions on the top of the marketplace page or search for "Material Theme Kit" in the extension side pane.

Keep in mind that VSCode themes only change the editor part. If you want some matching icons, there is a Material Icon Theme too.

Comment: Thanks but it's not the same (see edit above) and specially for ts files..